# Arcgis/Arcgis Online Domain coding table

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-online, domains, arcgis-collector

I'm having an issue with coding domains for ArcGIS online and am hoping someone has an idea. Maybe this can be done or not.

I have to edit a .GDB to add a couple things into a feature service for some inspections. Easy enough. The issue I'm having is the new fields in the feature class properties goes straight to the bottom below globalID, Creation Date, ETC... I can move this around in the attribute table but when I'm using the collector app or am on AGOL these new fields appear at the very end. Is there anyway to adjust this?

edit: the issue is in the .GDB when I try to adjust the "fields" in the feature class properties.

Comment: I'm not clear on how "domains" is a factor.  Are you able to control the order of fields that don't have coded value domains?

Comment: Are you configuring the popup in AGOL to rearrange the fields in the order you prefer?

Comment: @Kenbuja, I have tried rearranging in AGOL but can't seem to move columns in the attribute table.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall no, it seems when I'm trying to edit that order in .GDB I can't move items up or down the "Fields" table in the properties.

Comment: You don't move the fields in the attribute table. You have to do that in the popup by configuring it. [Configure pop-up](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/configure-pop-ups.htm)

Comment: @kenbuja Thank you for this, this is exactly what I was looking for. I knew there had to be a way to do it but couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 2):

You have to [configure](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/configure-pop-ups.htm) your popup to rearrange the fields in AGOL. This will then be reflected in the attribute table.